# Is there a way to write this term different $e^{x+e^x}$?

Tags: self-learning

I am a little confused what this actually means:

$e^{x+e^x}$

It is obviously not the same if I for example 
$$e^{x}:= \lambda \\  
e^{x+e^x} \neq \lambda^\lambda
$$

Comment: I think the last step should be $\lambda e^\lambda$ rather than $\lambda^\lambda$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as $$e^x\cdot e^{e^x}$$

Answer (score 0):

You're going wrong slightly in the last step:

$$e^x = \lambda$$

$$\implies e^{x+e^x} = e^x e^{e^x} = \lambda \times e^{\lambda}$$

Your expression
$$\lambda^{\lambda} = (e^{x})^{e^x}$$

See the difference?